# Does a quantum channel always preserve the identity matrix?

Tags: quantum-operation

Does a quantum channel (a completely positive trace-preserving map) always map the identity to the identity?

In other words, suppose that $ \mathcal{E}: \mathbb{C}^{N \times N} \to \mathbb{C}^{N \times N} $ is a quantum channel and $ I $ is the $ N \times N $ identity matrix. Then must we have that
$
\mathcal{E}(I)= I 
$?

Comment: Adding this long comment does *not* improve the question.

Comment: Ok I took it out and just posted it as an answer since it is too long for a comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, no reason it should. For instance, the amplitude damping
$$
\varepsilon_{AD}(\rho)=E_0\rho E_0^\dagger+E_1\rho E_1^\dagger
$$
with
$$
E_0=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\
0 & \sqrt{1-\gamma}\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
E_1=\begin{bmatrix}0 & \sqrt{\gamma}\\
0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
$$

We have
$$
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\varepsilon_{AD}(I)&=E_0 E_0^\dagger+E_1 E_1^\dagger \\
&=\begin{bmatrix}1+\gamma & 0\\
0 & 1-\gamma\end{bmatrix}\\
&\neq I\qquad \text{if }\gamma\neq 0
\end{alignat*}
$$

What must verify trace preserving operations is
$$
\sum_k E^\dagger_kE_k=I
$$
not
$$
\sum_k E_k E^\dagger_k=I
$$

Answer (score 6):

No, such maps are referred to as unital maps.

A counterexample is the replacement map
$$
\mathcal{E}(X) = \mathrm{tr}(X)\sigma
$$
defined for some density matrix $\sigma$.

Answer (score 4):

No. When this is the case the channel is said to be *unital*. A necessary and sufficient condition for a map $\mathcal E$ being unital is its adjoint $\mathcal E^\dagger$ being trace-preserving.

For example, a replacement channel like $\Phi(\rho)=\operatorname{tr}(\rho) \sigma$ is not unital unless $\sigma=I/d$.

You can have a look for example at chapter 4 of [Watrous' book](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ewatrous/TQI), which is about *unital channels and majorization*.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Just try some of the examples at [Canonical examples of quantum channels](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291810/canonical-examples-of-quantum-channels), such as #5 or #7.

Comment: Your linked question and answer are great references!

Answer (score 2):

Long comment related to something I really like about the accepted answer:

By Kraus' theorem any completely positive map can be written in the form
$$
\mathcal{E}(\rho)=\sum_{k} E_k \rho E_k^{\dagger}
$$
where $ \sum_k E_k^\dagger E_k \leq I $. And conversely given any set of operators $ \{ E_k \} $  such that $ \sum_k E_k^\dagger E_k \leq I $, then the linear map
$$
\rho \mapsto \sum_{k} E_k \rho E_k^{\dagger}
$$
will be completely positive.

Anyway for a quantum channel it is not just that the map $ \mathcal{E} $ is completely positive but also we ask that it be trace preserving. That is
$$
Tr(\rho)=Tr(\mathcal{E}(\rho))=Tr(\sum_{k} E_k \rho E_k^{\dagger})= \sum_k Tr(E_k \rho E_k^{\dagger})=\sum_k Tr( \rho E_k^{\dagger}E_k)=Tr(\sum_k \rho E_k^{\dagger}E_k)=Tr(\rho \sum_k E_k^{\dagger}E_k)
$$
So take the standard traceless basis + identity matrix we see that $ \rho $ and $ \sum_k E_k^{\dagger}E_k $ are trace orthogonal for all traceless choices of $ \rho $ and so $ \sum_k E_k^{\dagger}E_k  $ must be proportional to $ I $ and so since $ Tr(\rho)= Tr(\rho \sum_k E_k^{\dagger}E_k) $ it must in fact be that case that $ \sum_k E_k^{\dagger}E_k $ is exactly equal to $ I $.
$$
\sum_k E_k^{\dagger}E_k=I
$$
In other words, a completely positive map is exactly a
$$
\rho \mapsto \sum_{k} E_k \rho E_k^{\dagger}
$$
for $ \sum_k E_k^{\dagger}E_k \leq I $ while a completely positive trace-preserving map is exactly a
$$
\rho \mapsto \sum_{k} E_k \rho E_k^{\dagger}
$$
for $ \sum_k E_k^{\dagger}E_k = I $.

It is kind of interesting that a completely positive map is unital (maps identity to identity) if and only if
$$
I=\mathcal{E}(I)=\sum_{k} E_k I E_k^{\dagger}=\sum_{k} E_k E_k^{\dagger}
$$

In other words, a completely positive map is trace preserving if and only if
$$
I=\sum_{k} E_k^\dagger E_k
$$
while a completely positive map is unital if and only if
$$
I=\sum_{k} E_k E_k^{\dagger}
$$
These two facts are equivalent to the fact, stated in the answer by gIS, that a completely positive map is unital if and only if its adjoint is trace-preserving.

Although these conditions look superficially similar, and they coincide if the $ E_k $ are all hermitian or unitary or more generally if the $ E_k $ are all normal operators, they are in general completely different! And I love that the accepted answer brings up both these conditions and demonstrates this important distinction by using the non-normal operator $ E_1=\begin{bmatrix}0 & \sqrt{\gamma}\\
0 & 0\end{bmatrix} $